# How can I increment a value inside HTML?

Tags: javascript, increment

I'm completely new to JavaScript. I'm trying to increment a variable inside the HTML, it's not working.  Is my syntax wrong?

```
<script>
function rps() {
computerScore.value++;
computerScore.innerHTML = computerScore.value;
}
 </script>   
<html>
<b>computer score:</b><p id="computerScore" value="0">-</p>
<button type="button" onclick="rps()">Go</button><br>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not try to [access DOM elements as global variables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278/1048572), there's a [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) function for that.

Comment: Even if you look for a JS solution, it is worth noting that you can [handle counters with pure CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-increment.asp)!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`value` is not a valid attribute for the `<p>` tag.

I think you want something like:

```
function rps() {
    var computerScore = document.getElementById('computerScore');
    var number = computerScore.innerHTML;
    number++;
    computerScore.innerHTML = number;
}
```

...

```
<b>computer score:</b><p id="computerScore">0</p>
```

Comment: Actually number is a string until the ++ so perhaps number = +computerscore.innerHTML is more correct

Answer (score 1):

A few problems :

- on most browsers, you can't get an element by id just as a global property
- an attribute isn't always a property of an element (the value is only a property of input elements)

You can do this :

```
function rps() {
   // fetch the element :
   var element = document.getElementById('computerScore'); 

   // get the attribute, parse it and increment it :
   value = parseInt(element.getAttribute('value'), 10)+1; 

   // stores the incremented value :
   element.setAttribute('value', value);

   // and change the innerHTML (conversion to string is implicit)
   element.innerHTML = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple issues:

1. `computerScore` is nothing; you probably want `document.getElementById('computerScore')`
2. `value` on a `<p>` is not valid.  Use `data-value` or something instead (or

---

```
var computerScore = document.getElementById('computerScore');
function rps() {
    computerScore.dataset.value++;
    computerScore.innerHTML = computerScore.dataset.value;
}
```

Note that `dataset.value` is a string, but the `++` coerces it to an integer.

http://jsfiddle.net/vqPKZ/

I would also suggest using event bindings rather than event attributes, e.g. `button.addEventLister`

Comment: The `getElementById` should be called after DOMready, i.e. inside `rps`

Comment: @mplungjan http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

Comment: `dataset` is not old IE compliant, should use `getAttribute`

Answer (score 0):

```
The best option will be to pass in an event object from the rps() method in the HtML,       like this: rps(event).
Then retrieve it from the Javascript method like this:
function rps(event) {
var computerScore = event.CurrentTarget.innerText;
computerScore++;
computerScore = number;
}
```

Comment: you're incrementing an innerText value without seeing if it's an actual number?

Comment: I don't think the DOM can differentiate BTW numbers and string.

Answer (score -3):

```
var elm = whatever //assuming you select your element using the DOM
// update value
elm.innerHTML = +elm.innerHTML + 1;
```